# Adding Tridion DLLs to the Custom Resolver Solution

Tags: 2013, custom-resolver

I am moving my custom resolver from Tridion version 2011 to 2013 Sp1.

I set up the solution on my local machine for this. But I am unable to build it as following dependent assemblies are missing on my local machine.

Tridion.Common

Tridion.ContentManager

Tridion.ContentManager.Common

Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing

For earlier version(2011) I was using Development environment machine to build the solution and those dlls were present there in GAC.

Please help me build the custom resolver at my local machine. If it requires copy the dlls to my local machine and reference to my VS solution, which location on the Tridion server I can find the dlls?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy all Tridion.* dlls, from `<tridion>/bin/client` on the server to your local machine

Answer (score 4):

Those DLLs are indeed in the Content Manager Server GAC I doubt they are in your local computer GAC. Please note that since you are using a new version of Tridion you will need to use new DLLs versions. If you want to test it in your local machine you should copy the new dlls and reference them.

You should copy them from `[TRIDION_HOME]\bin\client`

Answer (score 2):

While the answers from @Will and @Eric are correct, I just wanted to add that there is no specific need to recompile your 2011 based Custom Resover in order to use it on 2013. If you still have the 2011 compiled assembly (DLL) of your Custom Resolver you can use that directly on your 2013 machine.

Once you start making changes, then it is advised to compile it against the 2013 assemblies which you can find in the `[TRIDION_HOME]\bin\client` directory indeed.